# Laravel Redirects POST request to GET

Tags: post, laravel, ckeditor

I have a very strange problem.

I'm Posting a form with some files to the server but for some reason Laravel is redirecting my request with GET and of course I get a `MethodNotAllowedException`.

Here is the code for my Routes: [Routes](http://pastebin.com/cP8tuyMP)

I'm testing the `route::post('/admin/article')`, just returning all the input

Here is my front-end form: [Form](http://pastebin.com/7F8WiiAi)

I'm using CKEditor

Every time I include an image inside the editor of "cuerpo", Laravel redirects my request to `GET /admin/article`, which does not exists.

The funny thing is that if I just input plain text it works fine ....

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and the solution for me was to use Laravels built-in form opener and change my routes, like this (Adding a named route):

```
Route::post('/admin/article/', array('as' => 'admin.addArticle', 'uses' => 'AdminController@addArticle'));
```

And open your form like this (using the named route):

```
echo Form::open(array('route' => 'admin.addArticle'));
```

I don't know why this works, and a normally created form does not.